# UICollectionView custom cells are not displaying

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` that contains custom `UICollectionViewCell`'s, here is the relevant code:

```
class customCell: UICollectionViewCell{
     var imgView = UIImageView()
     override init(frame: CGRect) {
         super.init(frame: frame)
         commonInit()
     }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit(){
         imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
         self.addcontentView.addSubview(imgView)
         //add constraints
    }
}


class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {
     private let imageLib = [...] //image file name strings

     override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell : IconCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(keyIconCellReuse , forIndexPath: indexPath) as! IconCollectionViewCell

        let image1 = (UIImage(named: imageLib[indexPath.row])?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate))!
        cell.imgView = UIImageView(image: image1)
        cell.imgView.tintColor = UIColor(white:0, alpha:0.7)
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = true

        return cell

    }

}
```

This is what it looks like now:

[image: 1o]

Comment: It seems like you adding new UIImageView for every loaded image. Could you share func setUp(imgString: String) method body?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `cell.setup(imageLib[indexPath.row])` adds a new `UIImageView` with the new image instead of reusing a existing one in the snipped code parts.

Please make sure to not initialize any views within `collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` for performance reasons. Just assign the appropriate image to the imageView that belongs to the cell.

Note that cells get reused a lot by a collection view.

**Edit**:

With the updated question, you are doing

```
    let image1 = (UIImage(named: imageLib[indexPath.row])?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate))!
    cell.imgView = UIImageView(image: image1)
    cell.imgView.tintColor = UIColor(white:0, alpha:0.7)
    cell.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

Just

```
let image1 = (UIImage(named: imageLib[indexPath.row])?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate))!
cell.imgView.image = image1
```

and do as much other setup as possible in `commonInit()`.

Comment: but if I want an array of cells loading an array of images, what would be a good way to do it -- should I put everything in the initialization code in the custom cell?

Comment: Let the collection view do it's job and select which cell to put where, just set the image according to the `indexPath`.

Comment: I just updated my code, but seem to have run into another problem, could you take a look?

Comment: This time, you're re-assigning the imageView. Just `cell.imgView.image = image`

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect your changes to the question, @user245954